# LINQ Query Using ALL

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine a photo tagging system...

```
    public class Photo
    {
      public IList<Tag> Tags {get;set;}
    }

    public class Tag
    {
      public string Name {get;set;}
    }

IList<Tag> tags = new [] {
                             new Tag{Name = "tag1"}, 
                             new Tag{Name = "tag2"}
                         };

IList<Photo> photos = GetAllPhotos();
```

And this line:

```
var results = //return photos when Photo.Tags contains BOTH tags
```

Is there a LINQ operator I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure:

```
// All the tags in "tags" are contained in p.Tags
var results = photos.Where(p => tags.All(tag => p.Tags.Contains(tag)));
```

or

```
// All the "tags" except the ones in p.Tags ends up as an empty set
var results = photos.Where(p => !tags.Except(p.Tags).Any());
```

EDIT: Note that this assumes that in reality you've got an appropriate equality implementation on Tag. Otherwise you'll need something like:

```
var results = photos.Where(p => !tags.Select(t => t.Name)
                                     .Except(p.Tags.Select(t => t.Name)).Any());
```

Comment: He probably wants a match on the tag names though...won't the Contains do an object comparison?

Comment: @jvenema: Edited. It would probably be better to make Tag implement `IEquatable<Tag>`

Comment: Actually I created an `IEqualityComparer<Tag>` and dropped that in the `Contains()` second argument. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
photos.Where(p => t.Tags.Contain(tags[0]) && t.Tags.Contains(tag[1]));
```

Its hard to know what operators `Tag` has.

Comment: won't match on the tag names (that'll be a byref operation) and I'm assuming he needs it to be flexible to expand to > 2 tags.

Comment: `tag[0]` should be `tags[1]` ?